# Paperclip.run 'jpegoptim' - problem with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

In my model, that has_attached_file, I have the following code:

```
before_post_process :jpeg_optim_compression

...

def jpeg_optim_compression
  path = attachment.queued_for_write[:original].path
  Paperclip.run("jpegoptim", "-o --strip-all #{path}")
end
```

And locally it works fine giving a following output:

```
[paperclip] jpegoptim -o --strip-all temporary_path_to_attachment  2>/dev/null
```

But deployed on the staging server it raises an error:

```
[paperclip] jpegoptim '-o --strip-all temporary_path_to_attachment' 2>/dev/null

Paperclip::PaperclipCommandLineError (Error while running jpegoptim. Expected return code to be 0 but was 3):
```

It took me some time to realize that these quotations were the cause (I supposed some file access problem  and others). After change to

```
Paperclip.run("jpegoptim -o --strip-all #{path}")
```

OR

```
Paperclip.run("jpegoptim -o --strip-all", "#{path}")
```

it works. Does anybody have an idea why is that?

Thanks for any suggestions!